# Define keyboards shortcuts in DrRacket

Tags: racket

I'm trying to define my own shortcuts for DrRacket.
I created the file necessary to make C-Z as undo (it's C-_ or C-x;C-u in emacs Keybindings) :

```
#lang s-exp framework/keybinding-lang
(keybinding "c:z" undo)
```

However, nothing happens when I add it to keyboards shortcuts.
What did I miss ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

a) You can enable C-Z, C-X, C-V, C-C, etc. editing style by checking "Enable keybindings in menus" in `Edit>Preferences>Edition>General`.

b) If you want only this particular binding to work, try with:

```
(keybinding "c:z" (lambda (editor evt) (send editor undo)))
```

You may need to restart DrRacket (not sure).